# gradle plugin uses a older/different version of a java library used in the code

Tags: java, gradle, swagger, version, libraries

I want to use the [swagger-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/tree/master/modules/swagger-gradle-plugin) from the [swagger-core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/) project to resolve my JAX-RS api to a OpenApiDefinition.

Now my problem ist that the plugin uses the library `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` in the version `2.9.10`. My project also uses this library but in the verson `2.10.0`. Now when I run the resolve task of the plugin I get a `VerifyError` because a class was changed. I already opened a [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3335) on github but the problem seems to be my configuration.

This is my gradle build file:

```
plugins {
  id "io.swagger.core.v3.swagger-gradle-plugin" version "2.0.10"
}

dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.0.10'
  implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.0"
  implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.0"
  ...
}

resolve {
  outputFileName = 'lcapi'
  outputFormat = 'YAML'
  prettyPrint = 'TRUE'
  classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
  resourcePackages = ['com.example.lc.api']
  resourceClasses = ['com.example.lc.api.LcRestController', 'com.example.lc.api.LcStateController']
  outputPath = file("${project.projectDir}/src/main/resources")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can get around it, but I think the simplest one is to create a new configuration that extends from the one you are using, but with a resolution strategy that forces the particular version of Jackson. It could look like this:

```
plugins {
  id "io.swagger.core.v3.swagger-gradle-plugin" version "2.0.10"
}

configurations {
    swagger {
        extendsFrom runtimeClasspath
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.10'
            force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.10'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.0.10'
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.0"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.0"
    // ...
}

resolve {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.swagger
    // ...
}
```

Note that I made it use the normal `runtimeClasspath` instead of the `testRuntimeClasspath` that you were using, as I expect the other one was just an attempt at making it work (you probably don't want test resources bleeding into the main resources).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the plugin does not seem to reach the api classes now. The output contains only the properties from the config file

Comment: Sorry, forgot that the runtime configuration does not include the compiled classes and resources. I've update the answer (added `sourceSets.main.output`).